# How to select vertices on different meshes in edit mode

Tags: vertices, edit-mode

I have two meshes. I'm trying to combine them by keying <kbd>W</kbd> and selecting *Bridge Edge Loops*. However, I can't select the vertices on both meshes for some reason. Any thoughts? Heres a pic:

[image]

Comment: You can't edit two objects at the same time and you can't join geometry from two separate objects. Join them into a single mesh with Ctrl+J in object mode.

Comment: There is an addon that does that, I forgot it's name, I was watching a youtube about addons and it was mentioned in it

Comment: Yeah, Ctrl + J is the only way to edit them both in Edit Mode. (Object mode to Ctrl + J)

Comment: I found it, i can duplicate it and change up the second one and combine it there. Thanks for the help everyone thou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Joining

<kbd>Tab</kbd> out of *Edit Mode*, select one mesh, <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the other, and key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to join them. <kbd>Tab</kbd> back into *Edit Mode*.

---

### Shading

**If the shading does not look weird (darker) on one or both of the meshes, ignore the following paragraph**.

Select one vertex of the weird one(s) and key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to select the rest of it(them). Key <kbd>T</kbd> to toggle open/close the *Toolshelf*, go to the *Shading/UVs* tab, and click on the *Recalculate* button. Key <kbd>A</kbd> once or twice to deselect the mesh(es).

---

### Bridging

**Do read this paragraph**.

Key <kbd>Alt</kbd>  and <kbd>RMB</kbd> while hovering over one of the edge loops. Do this for the other edge loop as well. This should select the whole loop. Key <kbd>W</kbd> to open the *Specials* pop up menu and select *Bridge Edge Loops*.

[image]

Comment: I tried joining them and screwed it up but found out i can duplicate it, and just change up the other one. I solved it but thanks for the help. I may try this out next time i mess up like before

Comment: @Catz_ Glad to here that you solved it! If my answer helped, please consider accepting it. It would help me greatly and make me very happy.

Comment: sure, im sure it'll help me later on :3

Comment: Shady you work so hard! :-)

Comment: @AnthonyForwood Thanks much. I have a lot of fun doing it.